# Copy from two workbooks into two worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder where I store two types of workbooks, which are `[person_name]-RESUME.xlsx` and
`[person_name].xlsx`. With my code, the user can select both of these files.

I'm looking to click on a button on a workbook, select both of these files, copy content in `[person_name]-RESUME.xlsx` to sheet1 and content in `[person_name].xlsx` to sheet2 and after that, close both files.

With my code I get an error `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set` and when I click "Debug" it highlights the `ElseIf` on my function, I've tried the function code with opening a single file and it works fine. Bellow is my code.

```
Sub opening_multiple_file()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim n_rows_A As Long, n_rows_B As Long, n_rows As Long
    'Opening File dialog box
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
        'Enabling multiple files select
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Clear
        
        'Only Excel files can be selected
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                'Opening selected file
                Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
                
                'Check if file is a resume
                If InStr(.SelectedItems(i), "-RESUME") Then
                    
                    n_rows_A = CountRows(myrange)
                    n_rows_B = CountRows(myrange.Offset(0, 1))
                    n_rows = WorksheetFunction.Max(n_rows_A, n_rows_B)
                    
                    ' Do the copy here
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(n_rows, 12).Value = _
                        myrange.Resize(n_rows, 12).Value
                    
                Else
                    
                    n_rows_A = CountRows(myrange)
                    n_rows_B = CountRows(myrange.Offset(0, 1))
                    n_rows = WorksheetFunction.Max(n_rows_A, n_rows_B)
                    
                    ' Do the copy here
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(n_rows, 12).Value = _
                        myrange.Resize(n_rows, 12).Value
                    
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Function CountRows(ByRef r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountRows = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        CountRows = 1
    Else
        CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```

Also I want to close the newly opened workbooks.

Comment: How will you identify the worksheets in the newly opened workbooks? Do you know their names, their index? Are you sure the right ones will always be active (selected)? Please do clarify. The error occurs because `myrange` is always `Nothing`. You forgot to use something like `Set myrange = Activesheet.Columns("A")` after `Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)`.

Comment: The newly opened workbooks always have the same layout and one sheet called "Sheet1". I've added that line of code, now I get `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Range From Another Workbook

- If the other stuff works, you could use something like the following in the `For Next` loop, including the function below it.

**Snippet**

```
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(i))
        myrange = getRange(wb.ActiveSheet, "A:B")
        
        If InStr(.SelectedItems(i), "-RESUME") Then
            ' Do the copy here
            ThisWorkbook("Sheet1").Range("A1") _
              .Resize(myrange.Rows.Count, 12).Value = _
              myrange.Resize(, 12).Value
        Else
            ' Do the copy here
            ThisWorkbook("Sheet2").Range("A1") _
              .Resize(myrange.Rows.Count, 12).Value = _
              myrange.Resize(, 12).Value
        End If
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

**Function**

```
Function getRange( _
    aWorksheet As Worksheet, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnAddress As String = "A", _
    Optional ByVal FirstRowNumber As Long = 1) _
As Range

    If Not aWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        With aWorksheet
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = .Columns(ColumnAddress) _
              .Resize(.Rows.Count - FirstRowNumber + 1) _
              .Offset(FirstRowNumber - 1)
            Dim cel As Range
            Set cel = rng.Find( _
              What:="*", _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                Set getRange = rng.Resize(cel.Row - FirstRowNumber + 1)
            Else
            ' All cells below first row are empty.
            End If
        End With
    Else
    ' Worksheet not defined.
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I've tried this code but got the same error that I was getting: `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`. The line that you suggested me adding on the comment above removed this error, but with this snippet and function I'm getting it again.

Comment: Using the snippet, in which line are you getting the error?

Comment: I get the error on `myrange = getRange(wb.ActiveSheet, "A:B")`